# Set offset and limit in zScan Redis

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I have this code on PHP redis:
(https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis)

```
$count = 10;
$it = null;
$redis->setOption(\Redis::OPT_SCAN, \Redis::SCAN_RETRY);
$pattern = '*"regionId":"564"*';
$result = $redis->zScan('my_key', $it, $pattern, $count);
```

I want to set offset using zScan. Is it possible?
Is there any workaround for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No - the `SCAN` family of commands use a stateless (server-wise) cursor to iterate the data structure that always starts at "0" (arbitrary, not related to offset). An offset, whatever you mean by that, is not included in the API.

It would be better if your question was to describe the use case and requirements - it isn't clear what you're trying to achieve.